# Problema con los servicios de sql-server 2012

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy realizando una aplicacion de escritorio con base de datos compartida(debido a que debo de intalar la aplicacion en varios equipos) y a la hora de iniciar los servicios para poderme conectar a la base de datos, el servicio de agente de sql no inicia.

A mi parecer es ese el problema por el cual no me puedo conectar a la base de datos de otro equipo, mientras que desde otro equipo(equipo el cual tiene el servicio de agente sql iniciado) no tiene problemas en conectar a la base de datos que tengo en mi equipo.

Answer (score 1):

asegúrate de tener activas las conexiones remotas y abierto en el firewall el puerto TCP correspondiente:

- Abre "SQL Server Manager", inicia sesión en él, cuando ingreses da clic derecho sobre el nombre del servidor en el explorador de objetos, selecciona "Propiedades" y luego ve a "Conexiones", ahí debes activar "Permitir conexiones remotas con este servidor". El puerto por defecto es el TCP 1433

Aquí hay más información: https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server/

Comment: Ya realice eso, el problema es que como comento, cuando yo intento iniciar el servicio Agente sql-server no me inicia, el unico modo en el cual "inicia", es si detengo todos los servicios, pero apenas inicio sesion en sql server studio ses detiene el servicio agente sql server. espero me puedas colaborar

Comment: Ya abriste el puerto TCP 1433 en el firewall donde está el servicio de SQL?. Aquí el procedimiento: https://computerhoy.com/noticias/internet/como-cerrar-abrir-puertos-del-firewall-windows-10-73051

Comment: Ya lo hice, ya tengo abierto el puerto pero ese no es tanto el inconveniente, el problema es que a la hora de iniciar los servicios, el servicio de Agente sql no inicia, el mismo sql server que estoy usando lo instale en otro equipo y en ese equipo los servicios funcionan correctamente (Aclaro que es mi primera vez realizando este tipo de acciones por eso no tengo conocimiento de que hacer), gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Mira en el visor de eventos de windows a ver si te dice algo que pueda servir. Oprime la tecla Windows y la tecla "X", luego escoge "Visor de eventos"

Comment: Exactamente que debo de buscar?, es la primera vez que oigo del visor de eventos

Comment: Mira en "Registros de Windows > Aplicación", busca errores que tengan como origen "MSSQLSERVER" o cualquier otro evento en el rango horario cuando tratas de conectarte y falla